# how to select a class when it is used multiple times in the site

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to select a particular class when it is used on multiple places . I want to show "disp-comment class" on clicking "comnt-area-view class" , comnt-area-view class and disp-comment class is used 2 times in the document

I tried with $(this).next ,  $(this).find(className) and $(clasName , this)  but it is not working

```
<script>


$(document).ready(function(){

 $(".disp-comment").hide();

     $(".comnt-area-view").click(function(){
     alert("hello");
        $(this).next(".disp-comment").show()

  });
});
</script>

<html>
 <a   class="btn-read-more comnt-area-view ">Add Comment</a><br/>
                  <div  class="user-name disp-comment">
                  <input type="text"  class="form-control cmnt-namefld" placeholder="Enter your name" >
                  <textarea class="cmnt-txtarea"  rows="4"  cols="40" name="comment" form="usrform"></textarea>

                  <input type="button" class="cmnt-btn" value="comment">

                  </div>

 <a   class="btn-read-more comnt-area-view ">Add Comment</a><br/>
                  <div  class="user-name disp-comment">
                  <input type="text"  class="form-control cmnt-namefld" placeholder="Enter your name" >
                  <textarea class="cmnt-txtarea"  rows="4"  cols="40" name="comment" form="usrform"></textarea>

                  <input type="button" class="cmnt-btn" value="comment">

                  </div>
</html>
```

Comment: did you try each? https://api.jquery.com/each/

Comment: @BerkAkkerman Why would you need that?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is because the `next()` element form `.comnt-area-view` is the `<br />`, not the `.disp-comment` element.

There's two fixes for this. The first would be to remove the `<br />` elements and make the `.comnt-area-view` elements `display: block` in CSS:

```
.comnt-area-view {
  display: block;
}
```

The second would be to use `nextAll()` instead:

```
$(this).nextAll('.disp-comment').first().show();
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to add a parent container & with respect to it you have to find the required area as below:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $(".disp-comment").hide();

  $(".comnt-area-view").click(function() {
    alert("hello");
    $(this).parent('.aParentDiv').find(".disp-comment").show();

  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="aParentDiv">
  <a class="btn-read-more comnt-area-view ">Add Comment</a><br/>
  <div class="user-name disp-comment">
    <input type="text" class="form-control cmnt-namefld" placeholder="Enter your name">
    <textarea class="cmnt-txtarea" rows="4" cols="40" name="comment" form="usrform"></textarea>

    <input type="button" class="cmnt-btn" value="comment">

  </div>
</div>

<div class="aParentDiv">
  <a class="btn-read-more comnt-area-view ">Add Comment</a><br/>
  <div class="user-name disp-comment">
    <input type="text" class="form-control cmnt-namefld" placeholder="Enter your name">
    <textarea class="cmnt-txtarea" rows="4" cols="40" name="comment" form="usrform"></textarea>

    <input type="button" class="cmnt-btn" value="comment">

  </div>
</div>
```